# dotCMS backup from .zip

Tags: dotcms

I have a problem with dotCMS. I have a site which is uploaded to the Internet and I want to export it to take care of this site locally on my computer. I've downloaded all data/assets from Maintenance -> Export dotCMS Content. I have a zip file with all content from this site. I managed and configured dotCMS locally on my computer. I have no idea how I can get access in dotCMS to my site from that zip file. In Maintenance menu I have no option to upload this site. I've read about folder dotCMS/starter.zip but I don't have anything like that. Can anyone tell step by step, how can I manage my site from zip file locally? Thx

Answer (score 0):

Create a new database for dotCMS and replace the starter.zip with your downloaded .zip.  Start dotCMS and it should import your site on initial startup.  There are some caveats - the databases and versions should match from the server you've downloaded the .zip from.

Answer (score 0):

So to add a couple things to Will's answer in case a few more details help:

- The easiest way to do what Will advised may be to start with a new dotCMS distribution.

  - Make sure the versions of both dotCMS and the database in the new installation match those of the site you made the backup from.
  - Go through all the normal install steps (including setting up a database), but before you actually start dotCMS, replace the starter.zip file in the ROOT (/dotserver/tomcat-8.0.18/webapps/ROOT) with your own ZIP file (renaming your file to starter.zip).
- Alternately, if you want to start with an existing install.

  - You still need to make sure the dotCMS and database versions match those of the site you backed up.
  - You still need to replace the starter.zip file with your backup ZIP file.
  - In addition, make sure you create a new DB (and update the context.xml file to point to it) *before* you start up dotCMS.  If you don't do this, the starter.zip file (your backup) will not get read when dotCMS starts up.